# Drupal 7 Bartik theme main menu

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-navigation

I am dabbling fresh with Drupal 7 and so far having little success with getting the Menu to behave the way I want it to. My CSS and PHP basics are strong, but understanding Drupal's system is in itself a huge challenge and hence my doubts.

For those acquainted with the Bartik theme, the main menu defaults itself in the header.

I am trying to create a floating/persistent menu that encapsulates the entire width of the website. But I am not sure where I need to go in and make the required changes.

One option I have is to remove the main menu from the Bartik header and then introduce the main menu block in the 'featured' region. Here the menu is rendering itself horizontally instead of vertically the way i want it to be.

Essentially the question is, How do I alter the main menu in the Bartik theme? Where do I need to get in and make changes.OH, and I have sub-themed it, just to let you know.

Thanks much !

Parijat

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow but it sounds like you need to create a new region to put the menu in. You add these in the themes .info file.

```
region[region_name] = Region name
```

Print the regions contents out in your themes page.tpl.php file.

Clear the cache and it will show up in the blocks page.

You can the style it how ever you want.

Comment: umm, I guess that is one way to do it, but I wanted to check if I can use the existing regions instead. Also, it seems like my primary menu is not being rendered on top of the header, any leads on how this happened? Thanks much !

Comment: You'd have more control if you made a new one. It was one of the more helpful things I found out when trying to learn Drupal.

Comment: so essentially add a new Drupal region. Then add the main menu block to this region and enhance it with any menu modules etc?

Comment: Yeah that'll do the trick. Use Firebug to get any specific CSs selectors you need but a new region will solve your problem.